# R Shiny: App contents not updated when logic implemented in custom module

Tags: r, shiny

I'm writing an R Shiny application that uses a custom module for chart rendering. When the user changes a dropdown value, chart contents should update. They don't for some reason, and I can't figure out why.

This is my chart module (`mod-chart.R`):

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


chartUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    plotOutput(outputId = ns("chart"))
  )
}


chartServer <- function(id, type, x, y, title) {
  moduleServer(
    id = id,
    module = function(input, output, session) {
      df <- reactive({
        data.frame(
          x = x,
          y = y
        )
      })

      # Chart logic

      # Line chart
      if (type == "line") {
        output$chart <- renderPlot({
          ggplot(df(), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
            geom_line(size = 2) +
            geom_point(size = 5)
        })

        # Bar chart
      } else {
        output$chart <- renderPlot({
          ggplot(df(), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
            geom_col()
        })
      }
    }
  )
}
```

And this is the contents of `app.R`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(gapminder)
source("mod-chart.R")
source("mod-table.R")


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "continent", label = "Continent:", choices = unique(gapminder$continent), selected = "Europe")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      chartUI(id = "chart-bar"),
      chartUI(id = "chart-line")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Filter the dataset first
  data <- reactive({
    gapminder %>%
      filter(continent == input$continent) %>%
      group_by(year) %>%
      summarise(
        avg_life_exp = round(mean(lifeExp), digits = 0),
        avg_gdp_percap = round(mean(gdpPercap), digits = 2)
      )
  })


  # Bar chart
  chartServer(
    id = "chart-bar",
    type = "bar",
    x = data()$year,
    y = data()$avg_life_exp,
    title = "Average life expectancy over time"
  )

  # Line chart
  chartServer(
    id = "chart-line",
    type = "line",
    x = data()$year,
    y = data()$avg_gdp_percap,
    title = "Average GDP per capita over time"
  )
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? It's like the update never propagates to the module code.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the reactive data frame and you can observe the changes.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

chartUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    plotOutput(outputId = ns("chart"))
  )
}

chartServer <- function(id, type, df, title) {
  moduleServer(
    id = id,
    module = function(input, output, session) {
      # df <- reactive({
      #   data.frame(
      #     x = x,
      #     y = y
      #   )
      # })
      
      # Chart logic
      
      # Line chart
      if (type == "line") {
        output$chart <- renderPlot({
          ggplot(df(), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
            labs(title=title() ) +
            geom_line(size = 2) +
            geom_point(size = 5)
        })
        
        # Bar chart
      } else {
        output$chart <- renderPlot({
          ggplot(df(), aes(x = x, y = z)) +
            labs(title=title() ) +
            geom_col()
        })
      }
    }
  )
}

library(gapminder)  

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "continent", label = "Continent:", choices = unique(gapminder$continent), selected = "Europe")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      chartUI(id = "chart-bar"),
      chartUI(id = "chart-line")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Filter the dataset first
  data <- reactive({
    df <- gapminder %>%
      filter(continent == input$continent) %>%
      group_by(year) %>%
      summarise(
        avg_life_exp = round(mean(lifeExp), digits = 0),
        avg_gdp_percap = round(mean(gdpPercap), digits = 2)
      )
    df$x <- df$year
    df$y <- df$avg_life_exp
    df$z <- df$avg_gdp_percap
    df
  })
  
  
  # Bar chart
  chartServer(
    id = "chart-bar",
    type = "bar",
    data, 
    # x = data()$year,
    # y = data()$avg_life_exp,
    title = reactive(paste("Average life expectancy over time in", input$continent))
  )
  
  # Line chart
  chartServer(
    id = "chart-line",
    type = "line",
    data,
    # x = data()$year,
    # y = data()$avg_gdp_percap,
    title = reactive(paste("Average GDP per capita over time in", input$continent))
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```